# mediaPlayer.setVolume didn't work when a phone in a silence

Tags: android

I customised an alarm clock, but it didn't work when the phone was in silent mode.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume of `MediaPlayer` depends on volume of `AudioManager` for `STREAM_MUSIC`.

For instance, set volume to max for stream music, before play your sound, and maybe after re-set value to old value (0):

This solution not respect choice of user. He doesn't to be disturb if he put device in silent mode !

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0);
```

Comment: It solved the problem by adding the codes before mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(), it did work even in a silence.